# Unable to give Google App Engine Service Account access to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine

I am a user of Google App Engine (GAE). In GAE there's an option we can backup the datastore to a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) Bucket. I have signed up GCS, enabled billing and created a Bucket successfully. However, when I try the backup function in GAE Console - Datastore admin, 
it gives me an error message like this:

*Start*
Backup Job Status
There was a problem kicking some off the jobs/tasks:
Bucket "myappxxxxxx-cloud-storage" is not accessible
*End*

I did some research online and found we need to add the GAE's Service Account as a team member of the GCS, I have done so, however, as I "Invite a user to collaborate on this application" and enter the server account email address which is like mygaexxxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com, I got no email because this is not supposed to be a real email account, I received no invitation and the Status is always in pending state

So what can I do now?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another indirect way on solving this problem is to write your own mail handler in GAE. then you can receive email sent to your GAE email address.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to use the gsutil command line approach to edit the Access Control List (ACL) as described in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview

By doing this there is no need for email invitation and the account does not show up in the console

Answer (score 1):

You can give the service account (and therefore your application) access to all of the Google services in one shot by adding it to the team in the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

As you point out, your can also do it using gsutil setacl/getacl commands as well. In this case, you're giving access to a specific bucket rather than all buckets in a Project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I've tried the "team" item in Google APIs Console but that brings me directly back to the App Engine Console's -> Administration -> Permissions Page.... which is where I got the issue of email invitation.

Comment: I'd guess your not clicking on the right link then - the developer console team is not the same thing as the GAE administrator page.

Comment: Do you mean the "Team" item in the list Overview, Services, Team, API Access, Billing, Google Cloud Storage on the page:
https://code.google.com/apis/console/

That redirects me to the https://appengine.google.com/permissions?app_id=xxxxxxxxx page

Comment: I tried this (adding service account as team member) with the new Cloud console and it worked, and allowed me to backup datastore to GCS.  I'm a little puzzled because I thought this was automatic with the new cloud console (my GAE is already associated with API project) but the backup was failing until I did this.